# Is this sum equality always holds?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose I know $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i$ converges to a value, can I write $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i$$

Also If I know that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$ converges to a value, can I write $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{m}a_{ij}\right)=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{m}a_{ij}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_{ij}$$

Please someone explain this.

Comment: Yes, you can write this.

Comment: Yes, this is true because this is precisely how infinite sums are _defined_.

Comment: Yes. You can do both. To prove these just "explot" the very definition of limit: Let $a$ be the result of the double summation, write down the definition of limit which will result in finite sums, then switch the sums (which is always allowed in finite sums)

Comment: I know the other way @GAVD is true

Comment: I know the other way @PrasunBiswas is true

Comment: The $\sum_i \sum_j a_{i j} = \sum_j \sum_i a_{i j}$ holds only if $\sum_i \sum_j |a_{i j}| < +\infty$ in general or if all $a_{i j}\ge 0$. It is a special case of the Fubini theorem.

Comment: @Gribouillis so the second one may not hold always?

Comment: It is wrong to express convergence of a series by 'less than infinity' unless the terms are non-negative. After all the sum could be minus infinity!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thanks. I edited accordingly.

Comment: @doctorme Yes the second one may not hold when the signs of $a_{i j}$ vary or when $a_{i j}$ are complex for example. I'll try to find a counterexample.

Comment: @Gribouillis in regards to your first comment, I think you means "holds if" rather than "holds only if"

Comment: @mathworker21 yes it is "holds if". I meant that when we don't have absolute convergence, we can't say if equality holds a priori. My sentence was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very definition of $\sum _{i = 1}^{\infty } {a}_{i}$ is

$$\sum _{i = 1}^{\infty } {a}_{i} = {\lim }_{n \rightarrow  \infty } \sum _{i = 1}^{n} {a}_{i}$$

when the limit exist.

For the double series, let

$${S}_{n m} = \sum _{i = 1}^{n} \sum _{j = 1}^{m} {a}_{i j}$$

A sufficient condition for ${\lim }_{n \rightarrow  \infty } \left({\lim }_{m \rightarrow  \infty } {S}_{n m}\right) = {\lim }_{m \rightarrow  \infty } \left({\lim }_{n \rightarrow  \infty } {S}_{n m}\right)$ is

$$\sum _{i = 1}^{n} \sum _{j = 1}^{m} \left|{a}_{i j}\right|  \leqslant  C  <  \infty $$

where $C$ does not depend on $n , m$.

There are weaker conditions such as both limits exist and for all ${\epsilon}  >  0$,
there exist ${N}_{{\epsilon}}$ and ${M}_{{\epsilon}}$ such that

$$\left|{S}_{n+i , m+j}-{S}_{n , m}\right|\le \epsilon$$

for all $n  \geqslant  {N}_{{\epsilon}} , m  \geqslant  {M}_{{\epsilon}} , i  \geqslant  0 , j  \geqslant  0$.

Counterexamples are easy to create because of the identity

$${a}_{i , j} = {S}_{i , j}+{S}_{i-1 , j-1}-{S}_{i , j-1}-{S}_{i-1 , j}$$

with the convention that ${S}_{p , q} = 0$ when $p = 0$ or $q = 0$.

So if we take for example

$${S}_{n , m} = \frac{n-m}{n+m+3}$$

we have a counterexample as ${\lim }_{n \rightarrow  \infty } \left({\lim }_{m \rightarrow  \infty } {S}_{n m}\right) =-1$
and ${\lim }_{m \rightarrow  \infty } \left({\lim }_{n \rightarrow  \infty } {S}_{n m}\right) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer.